# What is the dual basis for this functional?

Tags: linear-algebra

The  functional is given  by $E:V\rightarrow R$  by $E(p(x))=p(3)$  i.e  that  is  evaluation  at  $3$  where  $V$  is the  vector space  of  all polynomials  with  real  coefficients  and  the  given  basis  is  $\{1,x,x^{2},x^{3},x^{4},x^{5}\}$ .
I  have to  express  it  as  the  linear  combination  of  the  dual  basis.

Now if $\{E_{0},E_{1},E_{2},E_{3},E_{4},E_{5} \}$  is  the  dual basis then  $E$  can  be  expressed  as  $$E=\sum_{i=0}^{5} E(x^{i})E_{i} $$
 Then  by  evaluation  of  $E$  at  the  basis  vectors  I  get $$E=E_{0}+3E_{1}+9E_{2}+27E_{3}+81E_{4}+243E_{5}$$  and  $E_{i}$  is  a function  that  takes  all  basis  elements  except  for  $x^{i}$  to  $0$ .Writing  this  much  is  not  enough. I  need  to  know  how  exactly  do  the  $E_{i}$'s look $?$  How  to  proceed$?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the dual basis, you have $E_i(x^j)=\delta_{ij}$ ($1$ if $i=j$, $0$ otherwise).
Then,  for a polynomial $P$, $E_i(P)=E_i(\sum_{j=0}^5a_jx^j)=\sum_{j=0}^5a_jE_i(x^j)=a_i$.

Answer (score 1):

The dual basis consists of the coefficient functions: If $p = \sum a_nx^n$, then $E_n(p) = a_n$.